# I am trying to build web app and need some guidance on how I can create my polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to build a web app on laravel that is project management app that is meant for companies that works with different partners. However I am stuck on connecting all of them together. IS there a way for me to accomplish the following. Any guidance will be helpful.

Scenario and main tables that I need to connect all together.

Sites : Think of this as a main company that will register
   Users : all the users that will register on the account
   User Roles : different roles that will give them access to different things
   Partner sites : Different mini sites that will be owned by the main sites. these partner sites will also have different users with roles.

Question is can I connect all of them using plymorphic relationships.

ex:

An end user using the application needs to be belong to a main site and then a partner site within that main site. also will have the usual  user role attached to his name.

Comment: You probably want to make a polymorphic pivot for users. So that user can belong to many sites and many partner sites. See [polymorphic many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: I actually think you'll have less of an issue establishing the relationship and more of an issue juggling the sessions between multiple sites for a single user. A polymorphic relationship that's many-to-many will work fine out of the box for your setup, though.